# Trouble creating Spring Data JPA repository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

```
    @Repository
public interface JobRepository extends JpaRepository<Job, Long>{

}
```

Here is my repository. The error I'm getting is as follows. It seems like a pretty simple thing and I'm not sure how I could be screwing it up.

```
    2018-05-04T10:02:53,007 ERROR [main] SpringApplication id= marker= - Application startup failed org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'beanFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:223) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:702) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.vanguard.fig.risk.webservice.Application.main(Application.java:75) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:881) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:808) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:544) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:390) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:220) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1243) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 17 more
```

Here's part of the pojo I'm trying to persist

```
    @XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name="whatever")
public class Job implements Comparable<Job>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

I'm trying to do this with as little xml as possible. I have the below annotations on my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@ImportResource({"classpath*:/META-INF/**/spring-bootstrap.xml"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
```

I have my datasource defined in xml, and I added an entity manager factory as I was trying to troubleshoot but I didn't think it was necessary.

```
<bean id="rmsa" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" /> <!-- The number of connections you can have at once -->
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="3" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="3" />
        <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false" />
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="5" />
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="20000" />
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="5" />
        <property name="user" value="$riskInterface-{RMSA_USER}" />
        <property name="password" value="$riskInterface-{RMSA_PASSWORD}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="$riskInterface-{RMSA_JDBC_URL}" />
    </bean>




    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="rmsa" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Comment: Post your XML file

Comment: Please post the code of your JobRepository class.  Something appears to be wrong with its constructor.

Comment: Hi @Martin my understanding is that spring will generate the implementation for me. I have nothing in my JobRepository class, it just extends JpaRepository.

Comment: have you tried giving a name to your repository?  Here's how i declare mine :

@Repository("facilityDao")
public class FacilityDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, Facility> implements FacilityDao

Comment: I will try that. So you aren't letting spring produce the implementation automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. My enableJpaRepositories didn't reference the entityManagerFactory.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="package name", entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactory")
```

It is so hard finding the *right* example for anything spring related (or java for that matter). All the TIMTOWTDI is a killer.

Answer (score 0):

Please add Repository Package to entityManagerFactory Bean

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="repository.package" />
```